# Unity support for multitouch screens and touchpad laptop convertibles?

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, touchscreen

First, I would like to say that this post is not meant as just a mere complain about Ubuntu but I hope it is some constructive criticism.
I have been using Ubuntu for about 2 years consecutively in my main devices (and I had previously used it during college for a semester or two). So I am a fan, I am always hopeful that the Canonical team is working smart and listening to the community, and patiently waiting for Unity 8.

However, what the heck is going with with multi-touch support for screens and touch-pads? It's been a pain dealing with it! I have tried multiple programs the latest being touchegg & touchegg-cge. To try to make the touchpad and touch screen useful. Granted Ubuntu does recognize touches in touchpad and Ubuntu, and the touchpad can scroll with 2 fingers, but what about the rest? People should not have to use other apps or write a even a few lines of code to make their touch pads and screens be as functional as the norm (unless that is part of Ubuntu's vision). What about pinching for zooming in and out in the touch pad and in the screen? What about laptops that are 2 in 1, why is there no screen rotation? or touchpad locking when the device is in tablet mode?

The main reason for this post, is that these are not new technologies. They have been around for years. Most manufacturers have at least a series that are convertibles, while I've seen Ubuntu 15.10, 16.04, 16.10 passing by without caring about it?

I am currently trying ElementaryOS, which is a really new OS, and I was surprised that they do provide this things out of the box (I am actually writing this from ElementaryOS). Next I am trying Fedora which I have been recommended. But my point is, I was hopeful for Ubuntu. I was hopeful that Canonical was considering new technologies and listening to the community more.

And yes maybe there is a way to get that functionality in Ubuntu, in some computers doing foo and in others doing bar and using x and y applications, and then modifying their config files to z. But that's.. really not the point of Ubuntu, or is it?

tl dr: Why is Ubuntu not providing standard functionality for multitouch touchpads and touchscreens, while other new OSs (even new ones) are ?? It's already 2017 guys...

Comment: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) ?

Comment: "tl dr: Why is Ubuntu not providing standard functionality for multitouch touchpads and touchscreens, while other new OSs (even new ones) are ?? It's already 2017 guys.." - touchscreens?

Comment: lol the title says alsomultitouch screens and in laptop convertibles (to work as tablets). I'm really confused by your comment.. Maybe you meant it for another post?

Answer (score 1):

Don't mean to earn any reputation. But the multitouchscreen is supported out of the box. The application lack multitouchscreen support but that is not really a fault of Ubuntu but more like a lack of interest in the community. It has been always a rare amount of people using touchscreen devices on a normal desktop. Most people use Android or Ubuntu Touch instead. Also most touchscreens are glare.

There are even two application for adding multitouch support on applications that do not support it very well.

1) [Easystroke](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easystroke/) - requires mtrack to work with Multitouch. Very good if you do not want to use standard strokes but define them all by yourself. But seems to require [a patch to work with mtrack](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/pull/9/commits/c328ef36d7d85e899fa1ccbc9f11aa1b2317f7bc).

2) Touchegg: UI for configuration has to be downloaded and installed separately). For starters the superior option (you mentioned it yourself)

Concerning Wayland / Mir I really have not looked into this concerning multitouchscreens but it*s supported too.

Start looking for Qt/QML-based apps. They are most likely to have Multitouch support.